# Python SQLITE 3 INSERT INTO not working

Tags: python, database, bash, sqlite

I have this python script, when I run it I have no error but my database is always empty...

```
import sqlite3
import subprocess

conn = sqlite3.connect('stockage.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

filename = '../Collecteur/collecteur_cpu_reseau.txt'
proc_name = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"1p",filename])
proc_freq = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"2p",filename])
proc_core = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"3p",filename])
proc_hyperthreading = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"4p",filename])
proc_architecture = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"5p",filename])
proc_cache_L1 = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"6p",filename])
proc_cache_L2 = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"7p",filename])
proc_cache_L3 = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"8p",filename])
proc_virtualisation = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"9p",filename])
proc_load_average = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"10p",filename])
ip_infos_addr_ipv4 = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"11p",filename])
ip_infos_addr_ipv6 = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"12p",filename])
ip_publique_addr = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"13p",filename])
carte_reseau = subprocess.check_output(["sed","-n",r"14p",filename])

cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO sonde_cpu_reseau(proc_name,proc_freq,proc_core,proc_hyperthreading,proc_architecture,proc_cache_L1,proc_cache_L2,proc_cache_L3,proc_virtualisation,proc_load_average,   ip_infos_addr_ipv4,ip_infos_addr_ipv6,ip_publique_addr,carte_reseau) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",(proc_name,proc_freq,proc_core,proc_hyperthreading,proc_architecture,proc_cache_L1,proc_cache_L2,proc_cache_L3,proc_virtualisation,proc_load_average,
    ip_infos_addr_ipv4,ip_infos_addr_ipv6,ip_publique_addr,carte_reseau))
conn.commit()
```

`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, the triple quote is for keeping the indentation if I understand well

Comment: I'm confused why you need `sed`

Comment: Where are you creating the table?

Comment: Cricket -> I need sed to retrieve information in a file
kr29 -> I create the table into another py script. A link if you want to see : http://pastebin.com/uki1nguc

Comment: `import os; print(os.path.abspath('stockage.db'))`. I'm guessing that's not the file you think it is.

Comment: How are you browsing the data? Are you using a sqlite browser? If yes then it displays the tables in alphbetical order. You are propbably only seeing your `alert` table. The dropdown menu will have the other table `sonde_cpu_reseau`

Comment: Wayne -> the print return the exact path I think it is..
KR29 -> I use SQliteman and I see the both tables but empty.. Here is a screen of the software : http://hpics.li/324b533

Comment: Make sure you do a `conn.close()`, otherwise changes may be lost.  See example here https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: cdarke --> I try, but nothing more.. And i see the properties of stockage.db and I think the script never access the file because the date of "Acccessed" or "Modified" never change

Comment: I have seen that SQliteman shows the table as empty when some of its values are missing. Use this browser instead http://sqlitebrowser.org/ . You should be able to see what values are missing. Other than that I dont see why the table is not populated

Comment: KR29 --> You're right, and thanks for the software. My sqlite Request was good but SQLiteman won't show the record if a column have a missing values.. The problem is fixed with SQLITEBROWSER thanks a lot